# replacing einsum with normal operations

Tags: python, linear-algebra, numpy-einsum, einsum

I need to replace einsum operation with standard numpy operations in the following code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(128, 16, 8, 32)
b = np.random.rand(256, 8, 32)
output = np.einsum('aijb,rjb->ira', a, b)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What's the motivation for the replacement? speedup?

Comment: yes indeed, but with backpropagation ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to align to a similar shape and broadcast multiply, then `sum` and reorder the axes:

```
output2 = (b[None, None]*a[:,:,None]).sum(axis=(-1, -2)).transpose((1, 2, 0))

# assert np.allclose(output, output2)
```

But this is much less efficient as it's producing a large intermediate (shape `(128, 16, 256, 8, 32)`):

```
# np.einsum('aijb,rjb->ira', a, b)
68.9 ms ± 23.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# (b[None, None]*a[:,:,None]).sum(axis=(-1, -2)).transpose((1, 2, 0))
4.66 s ± 1.65 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Shapes:

```
# b[None, None].shape
#a  i    r  j   b
(1, 1, 256, 8, 32)

# a[:,:,None].shape
#  a   i  r  j   b
(128, 16, 1, 8, 32)
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ir0098 out of curiosity, why did you want that?

Comment: in fact, seems einsum becomes slow when employing within solutions requiring error back propagation for illposed problems.

Comment: @ir0098 I would recommend to ask a follow-up question on how to improve the einsum operation, I believe there are some users with a potential answer to that (might be negative). If you do, make sure to use the [tag:numpy] tag and to add a dummy example to reproduce the backpropagation.

Comment: sure, and one again, thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(128, 16, 8, 32)
b = np.random.rand(256, 8, 32)

# Reshape 'a' to (128, 16, 256, 32)
a_reshaped = a.transpose(0, 2, 1, 3).reshape(128, 16, -1)

# Reshape 'b' to (256, 8, 32)
b_reshaped = b.transpose(0, 2, 1)

# Perform matrix multiplication between reshaped 'a' and 'b'
output_reshaped = np.matmul(a_reshaped, b_reshaped)

# Reshape 'output' to (256, 128, 16)
output = output_reshaped.reshape(256, 128, 16).transpose(1, 2, 0)
```

This code reshapes the input arrays a and b and then performs a matrix multiplication using np.matmul. The result is reshaped to match the desired output shape.

Comment: Good ideas here, but I get a `ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 32 is different from 256)` when running your code, and I cannot understand why (column and row dimensions of the matrix product are matching).